# java can't find method setTitle() and show() in intellij of javafx project(in Ubuntu machine)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

when i try to run my first hellWorld project in intellij(the latest version) it shows me

```
Error:(15, 21) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setTitle(java.lang.String)
  location: variable primaryStage of type @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull javafx.stage.Stage
Error:(16, 31) java: no suitable constructor found for Scene(javafx.scene.Parent,int,int)
    constructor javafx.scene.Scene.Scene() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor javafx.scene.Scene.Scene(boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Error:(17, 21) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method show()
  location: variable primaryStage of type @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull javafx.stage.Stage
```

anyone who has the solution please help me i'm new to javafx

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing the code for your hello world project as well and editing it into your original post? Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure all the required jars are in the classpath.

Comment: Please add your code so that we can help you solve your issue

Comment: If you're using Java 11+ note the JavaFX libraries were removed from the JDK. You now have to add them as an external dependency just like any other library. See [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).